# Simple and Best way to convert Dictionary<key, List<obj>> to List<obj> in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Let's say that we have a dictionary like this

```
Dictionary<key, List<obj>>
```

I want to get all values as list like this

```
List<obj>
```

e.g. There are 3 keys in dictionary, key1, key2, key3.

```
2 values for key1
3 values for key2
5 values for key3
```

result should be one list that has 10 values!

I think it may be done with foreach and ToList().
I hope simpler and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Values` property to get all values from dictionary. And [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) linq extension to flatten sequence of lists into sequence of objects:

```
dictionary.Values.SelectMany(v => v).ToList()
```

Comment: For downvoter: this answer is only 1 character longer than `(x => x.Value)` option. But it does not create  `KeyValuePair` objects which we don't need here. Also it narrows context faster which makes the intent more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var list = dictionary.SelectMany(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

From the docs:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

All you have to do is to specify the selector - the IEnumerable you want to select for each KeyValuePair, which is obviously the value.